# Javascript Fetch upload files to Python Flask-restful

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-restful

I am new to python and javascript, I have been given a task to create a form in which I need to upload a file. I need to hit the backend (flask restful API). I have been told this is how i need to send request

```
requests.post(f"{server}/v1/cand", files={f"{target}_cand": cand_data})
```

I tried hitting from javascript using fetch api and i get 201 created response but the file that backend receive is empty.
i don't know if i am formatting the request correctly,

```
 var data = new FormData()
  data.append('files', files[0])
  data.append('name', fileName)
  console.log(data.get('files'))
fetch("http://localhost:5001/v1/cand",{
  method:"POST",
  body: {files:files[0]},
})
.then(function(response){
  return response.json()
})
.then(function(data){
  console.log('success')
  console.log(data)
})
```

This is how it is being received in the backend

```
    def post(self):
    cand= []
    for f in request.files:
    //do something
```

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: The frontend part looks fine. I'm guessing (since it's incomplete) the problem is in the backend part. You may want to compare your backend with the doc https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: i was being told that the backend runs without a problem if being hit by swagger, I am unsure if am sending the data correctly from the frontend. when I checked in the networks , the object indeed is being sent in the payload

Comment: Or maybe it's just the file field name. In the python code, the file field name is `{target}_cand` but in the js code it's `files`

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, couldn't believe I missed the obvious. You don't send the `FormData` instance in the request. You may want to do it like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#fileUpload').addEventListener('change', event => {

  let files = event.target.files
  let fileName = files[0].name
  
  // your code start here
  var data = new FormData()
  data.append('files', files[0]) // maybe it should be '{target}_cand'
  data.append('name', fileName)
  console.log(data.get('files'))

  // let url = "http://localhost:5001/v1/cand"
  let url = "https://tongsampah.herokuapp.com"
  fetch(url,{
    method:"POST",
    // body: {files:files[0]}, // wrong
    body: data,
  })
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json()
  })
  // .then(function(data){ // use different name to avoid confusion
  .then(function(res){
    console.log('success')
    console.log(res)
  })

})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
```

> the https://tongsampah.herokuapp.com is just a dummy api server that I use to test. It will returns the request details as a response

You may want to make sure the field name is correct (eg. `{target}_cand` -- I don't know what target value is)

Comment: It worked, Target was the filePath and when I added data it went smooth, Thank you so much, I had been working on this for like 8 hours.